# TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;id&#39; of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

**Routes:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const controller = require('../controllers/imoveis-controller');

router.get('/:id', controller.getById);
router.get('/', controller.getAll);
router.post('/', controller.post);
router.put('/:id', controller.put);
router.delete('/', controller.delete);

module.exports = router;
```

**Controller:**

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize');
const database = require('../config/dbconnection');
const model = require('../models/imoveis');
const repository = require('../repositories/property_repository');

exports.getAll = repository.getAll;

exports.getById = repository.getById;
```

**Repository**

```
const dbConnect = require('../config/dbconnection');
const model = require('../models/imoveis');




exports.getAll = (req, res, next) => model.findAll()
    .then((result) => {
        res.send(result);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('Erro: ' + errror));

exports.getById = (req, res, next) => model.findByPk(res.params.id)
    .then((result) => {
        res.send(result);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('getById error: ' + error));
```

Quando eu chamo o o metodo GetAll funciona normalmente, mas quando chamo o metodo getById e passo o Id pela url ele da o erro: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined*

e eu estou utilizando o **body-parser**:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

tem algum outro meio de recuperar o id e passar ele como parâmetro para o repository?